# Docker Django Error: CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to dockerise my django project with postgresql but have been running into this same problem time and time again.

```
web_1  | CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
```

I've my environment variables in a .env set to:

.env:

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and use the python-decouple module to configure them in settings.py

```
from decouple import config
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False)
ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(sep=' ')
```

Running the project:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

works perfectly fine with no errors. However, when it comes to running:

```
docker-compose up
```

I get the following output

```
Starting postgres_db ... done
Starting project_web_1 ... done
Attaching to postgres_db, project_web_1
postgres_db |
postgres_db | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_db |
postgres_db | 2021-07-30 17:58:52.695 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_db | 2021-07-30 17:58:52.696 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_db | 2021-07-30 17:58:52.696 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_db | 2021-07-30 17:58:52.747 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_db | 2021-07-30 17:58:52.887 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-07-30 17:58:34 UTC
postgres_db | 2021-07-30 17:58:52.950 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
project_web_1 exited with code 1
```

I've tried setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']` and have included other hosts too, but I cannot find anything that works.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

docker-composse.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes: 
      - .:/django
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on: 
      - db
  
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    container_name: postgres_db
```

Comment: Try with `ALLOWED_HOSTS='localhost 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0:8000'`. Put the quotes in .env and try.

Comment: If you print(ALLOWED_HOSTS) in settings.py after you defined it, what is the output?

Comment: What's the problem with `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']`? If you're running with compose, your hostname should be `'web'` based on your compose file. So try `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['web']`, but the wildcard should work.

Comment: On another note, I wouldn't have the `Dockerfile` run `runserver`. If you really want to use `runserver`, have the compose file do that; https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha Unfortunately, I still get the same error

Comment: @EduardoMatsuoka Through these two print statements: `print(type(config('ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(sep=' ')))
print(config('ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(sep=' '))`, I got `<class 'list'>
['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0:8000']` respectively

Comment: @markwalker_ What you said makes complete sense... however both the wildcard and 'web' give out the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found no evident solution to the problem, thus, seeing that nothing was *logically* incorrect, I decided to start the whole project again (beginning from a docker container) and copy over the django files that I needed. It now works like a charm.

I appreciate the people who took the time to answer.
Follow https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/ as @markwalker_ suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

for some weird reason it worked for me only when i started django with gunicorn and nginx idk why, i even cloned my repository somewhere else but with no effect, also i started django shell and settings was debug is False although it was hardcoded True...
this thing killed my day (: